# Append only unique matrices to a list

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

How can I check if a [2x2] matrix is in a list and append it if not:

```
import numpy as np

l = None

for i in range(10):
    mat = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=4)
    mat = mat.reshape(2,2)
    
    if l is None:
        l = [mat]
    
    if mat not in l:
        l.append(mat)
```

Give me an error with: `*** ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

I can do it with:

```
import numpy as np

l = None

for i in range(100):
    mat = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=4)
    mat = mat.reshape(2,2)
    
    if l is None:
        l = [mat]
    
    tmp_diff = [np.max(np.abs(elem - mat)) for elem in l]
    if np.min(tmp_diff) > 0:
        l.append(mat)
```

But this seems inefficient.

How can I only append unique matrices to a list?

Answer (score 1):

Numpy's matrix equality does not perform as with regular lists, as it operates on array axes.
Instead, you can rely on one of the 2 approaches:

**1**) collect unique 4-item lists (relying on list equality check) and eventually convert the list of lists into a array of  arrays each of shape`(2, 2)`:

```
mtx_list = []

for i in range(10):
    lst = np.random.choice(2, size=4).tolist()
    if lst not in mtx_list:
        mtx_list.append(lst)

mtx_list = np.array(mtx_list).reshape(-1, 2, 2)
print(mtx_list)
```

---

**2**) create all sub-matrices at once and filter out duplicates with [`np.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html):

```
mtx_list = np.array([np.random.choice(2, size=(2,2)) for i in range(10)])
mtx_list = np.unique(mtx_list, axis=0)
print(mtx_list)
```

---

Sample output:

```
[[[0 0]
  [0 0]]

 [[0 0]
  [0 1]]

 [[0 1]
  [0 1]]

 [[0 1]
  [1 0]]

 [[0 1]
  [1 1]]

 [[1 0]
  [0 1]]

 [[1 1]
  [1 1]]]
```